# Just started learning jquery and code not working

Tags: jquery

I'm going through a beginner's tutorial and already my code isn't working. I can't for the life of me see how my code differs from the tutorial code provided. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<title>To Do List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>To Do List</h1>
<form name="checkListForm">
    <input type="text" name="checkListItem" value="Add to do item> here!"/>
</form>
<button>Add</button><br/>
<div id="toDoItems">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
        $('#toDoItems').append("<p>"toAdd"</p>");
    });
});
```

Comment: you need to include jquery library in your page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include jQuery library before including your script

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
    <head>
        <title>To Do List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        <!-- including jQuery library                                               -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
        <form name="checkListForm">
            <input type="text" name="checkListItem" value="Add to do item> here!"/>
        </form>
        <button>Add</button><br/>
        <div id="toDoItems">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and concatenate string using `+`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
        $('#toDoItems').append("<p>" + toAdd + "</p>");
        //                       ----^-------^------
    });
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/C6WpC/1/)</kbd>

If it's not working then instead of including external script file include code in the page, it's working perfectly in my browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
    <head>
        <title>To Do List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        <!-- including jQuery library                                               -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('button').click(function() {
                    var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
                    $('#toDoItems').append("<p>" + toAdd + "</p>");
                    //                       ----^-------^------
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
        <form name="checkListForm">
            <input type="text" name="checkListItem" value="Add to do item> here!"/>
        </form>
        <button>Add</button><br/>
        <div id="toDoItems">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If it's working then there will be some problem with the path of your script `script.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery before your `scripts.js`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

as well as using `+` to concatenate your value in javascript:

```
$('#toDoItems').append("<p>" + toAdd +"</p>");
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about linking to the jquery library. V much a beginner!  However, it's still not working...?? (and I did add the '+'s too)

Comment: it's still not working though! I've added the link to the jquery library in the HTML page and added the +'s. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Check Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/be7rJ/. You need to make sure all the files are loaded properly. Also check to see any error in the console or not

Comment: thanks all. It's still not working - and when I add the jquery into the html file everything disappears. I'm doing this on my work pc, I'll try later on my laptop at home to see if that's any better - maybe there's some kind of block on the work computers? Anyway, thanks everyone for your time - this is a great forum!

Comment: Works fine at home, so must be some kind of Java block on the work PCs. Thanks for all the help :)